# Is it possible that changes in my program sometimes does not apply because my SQL Server database is slower than my program?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sqlclient

I use this code to determine the next ID of an article. So if I were to add a new article to my database then it would recieve that ID.

But sometimes when I delete an article then the ID number is wrong when sometimes it's not (it has nothing to do with the code from the delete function)

```
try
{
    string s = "select max(Id) as Id from dbo.Artikelen";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);
    con.Open();

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dr.Read();

    int i = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id"].ToString());

    labelArtikelID.Text = (i + 1).ToString();
    con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: why dont you use identity to auto increment the ID? so you dont need to select MAX(ID) and add it by 1 manually

Comment: Obviously it will work like this if your Id column is AutoIncremented,
i guess you need to remove AutoIncrement property from Id field and manually input this which might help you

Comment: by the way, maybe you are having a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: This is a **horribly bad idea** to use `select max(id)+1` .... in an system with multiple concurrent users (and which SQL Server database system isn't??), then you're **guaranteed** to get duplicates - really really horribly bad - ***DO NOT DO THIS!*** Seriously ..... this is what the `INT IDENTITY` column are for - then the **SQL Server database** handles all the nitty-gritty details, and it's **concurrency-safe** !

Comment: Also, if you're retrieving only a single row, single value (like your `select max(id)` ) from a SQL Server database, you should use `.ExecuteScalar()` instead of `.ExecuteReader()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this code is an attempt to retrieve the automatically generated ID. MAX +1 will only work if no-one else inserts or deletes rows between `INSERT` and `SELECT`. This is extremely unlikely in a real application.

The easiest way to retrieve the new ID is to add an [OUTPUT clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) in the INSERT statement itself, and retrieve the returned ID.

```
INSERT INTO Artikeln(...)
OUTPUT inserted.ID
VALUEs(...)
```

Executing the INSERT command with ExecuteScalar will return the new ID.

[IDENT_CURRENT('tablename')](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ident-current-transact-sql) should be used to retrieve a table's *current* identity value, eg:

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.Artikeln') AS CurrentID;
```

Deleting new entries means that `MAX(ID)` will return the ID of one of the latest entry, not even the current identity value.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it will work like this if your Id column is AutoIncremented, i guess you need to remove AutoIncrement property from Id field and manually input this which might help you

Comment: The ID in the database has to be AutoIncremented

Comment: then you will get incorrect Id if you try to remove an item,

Ex:
you have added 10 items, and removed last 3 then try to add an item to the table it will show the id as 11 which is correct, but i guess you are expecting this to be 8 am i right